# How to get the text only from the getcontent method

Tags: visualforce, getcontent

I have used the following code to get the content of the page but it shows the content along with style, HTML code so how to get content only from the webpage.

My Code is :

```
PageReference page = new PageReference('http://yahoo.com');
content = page.getContent().toString();  
system.debug('<<contect>>>'+content);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use the following code in vf page. thats fine.

```
 <apex:outputText value="{!yourapex code proerty}" escape="false"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use Jsoup java library

the code is

```
public static String html2text(String html) {
    return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
}
```

you can also use

```
replaceAll("\\<.*?>","")
```

method to eliminate html tags

Comment: in where i have to use this replaceAll("\\<.*?>","") and what is the data type of the jsoup? it shows the declaraion error

Comment: [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) is written in Java not Apex so can't be used within Salesforce.

Comment: SO how to use in apex class. i need apex code.